# Initial conditions for 2 IIR causal filters applied to the same time-series consecutively

Tags: filters, python, filter-design, infinite-impulse-response

I have a buffer of shape (n_samples, n_channels) in which new samples are coming in at regular intervals and old samples are discarded. In this example, the buffer array is called `data` and the array of new samples coming is called `new_data`.

This buffer and all the new samples are filtered with IIR causal filters, but different channels might be filtered by different filters. Assuming I have 6 channels (0-indexed), and 2 filters:

- filter1 applied to channels `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`
- filter2 applied to channels `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`

How should I handle the initial conditions `zi` used for `new_data` on the overlapping channels `2` and `3`.

Pseudo-python-code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import sosfilt, sosfilt_zi

# data buffer which receives new samples at each iteration
data = ...  # array of shape (n_samples, n_channels)

sos1 = ...
zi1 = None
zi_coeff1 = sosfilt_zi(sos1)[..., np.newaxis]
picks1 = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])  # channel selection

sos2 = ...
zi2 = None
zi_coeff2 = sosfilt_zi(sos2)[..., np.newaxis]
picks2 = np.array([2, 3, 4, 5])  # channel selection

# first iteration
if zi1 is None:
    zi1 = zi_coeff1 * np.mean(data[:, picks1], axis=0)
data_filtered, zi1 = sosfilt(sos1, data[:, picks1], axis=0, zi=zi1)
data[:, picks1] = data_filtered

if zi2 is None:
    zi2 = zi_coeff2 * np.mean(data[:, picks2], axis=0)
data_filtered, zi2 = sosfilt(sos2, data[:, picks2], axis=0, zi=zi2)
data[:, picks2] = data_filtered

# second iteration, zi's are not None anymore
new_data = ...  # array of shape (n_samples, n_channels), new samples
data_filtered, zi1 = sosfilt(sos1, new_data[:, picks1], axis=0, zi=zi1)
new_data[:, picks1] = data_filtered

data_filtered, zi2 = sosfilt(sos2, new_data[:, picks2], axis=0, zi=zi2)
new_data[:, picks2] = data_filtered

# concatenate buffer
data = np.vstack([data, new_data])
```

During the second iteration, are `zi2` still valid despite the data on channels `2` and `3` being already filtered through `filter1`?

EDIT: Is it valid to filter the initial conditions `zi2` of channels `2` and `3` using `filter1`:

```
zi2[2:4] = sosfilt(sos1, zi2[2:4], axis=0, zi=zi1)[-1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider one channel $x[n]$ being filtered by a cascade of two biquads $H_0$ and $H_1$:

$$x \rightarrow \fbox{$H_0$} \xrightarrow{\text{$u$}}\fbox{$H_1$} \rightarrow y$$

The transfer functions are (with normalization by $a_{*0}$) :
$$H_0(z) = \frac{b_{00} + b_{01}z^{-1} + b_{02}z^{-2}}{1 + a_{01}z^{-1} + a_{02}z^{-2}}$$
$$H_1(z) = \frac{b_{10} + b_{11}z^{-1} + b_{12}z^{-2}}{1 + a_{11}z^{-1} + a_{12}z^{-2}}$$

In the time domain:

$$u[n] = b_{00}x[n] + b_{01}x[n-1] + b_{02}x[n-2] - a_{01}u[n-1] - a_{02}u[n-2]$$
$$y[n] = b_{10}u[n] + b_{11}u[n-1] + b_{12}u[n-2] - a_{11}y[n-1] - a_{12}y[n-2]$$

From these you can see why **the states need to be kept separate for each filter**.

What you're suggesting would yield:
$$y[n] = b_{10}u[n] + b_{11}x[n] + b_{12}x[n-1] - a_{11}u[n] - a_{12}u[n-1]$$